# Этимология слова "оглоед"

Tags: этимология, словообразование, значение-слов

Какая этимология у слова **оглоед**? Ну, корень ***-ед-*** — это понятно, но что же он ест?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не что, а как. 
Огло - очень много, сильно, без удержу.  Отсюда же, кстати, "оглоушить" - сильно удрарить по ушам (или,может, до звона в ушах).
А "оглобля", видимо, не связано, хотя возможно и народное переосмысление.