# Что гложет оглоед?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В вопросе [Этимология слова "оглоед"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3031) разбирается значение слова "оглоед", но ничего не говорится об этимологии.

Хотелось бы узнать, родственны ли слова "глодать" и "оглоед"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Этимология слова "оглоед"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4)

Comment: Как автор единственного ответа на тот вопрос подтверждаю, что вопрос другой. По крайней мере во второй части исходной формулировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что гложет оглоед?

Здесь смотрите, не надо дублировать вопросы.
[Этимология слова "оглоед"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3031)

> Огло это от глодать?

А вот это вопрос интересный.
Точно сказать не могу, этимология обоих слов довольно темная, особенно наречия "огло" (жадно, сильно). Но на каком-то уровне есть семантическое пересечение - по значению именно с едой связанного (невоздержанно есть, "жрать"). 
Так что может быть, хотя уверенности нет никакой.